# Good slant vials?

Tags: yeast-cultures, slants

I've been looking into making yeast slants, thinking it could be fun.  I've been looking for some test tubes online, and have a few questions.

- Is it tough to use test tubes with stoppers rather than screw on caps?
- Will I be able to properly sanitize polyethylene, or should I spend the extra few bucks on glass?
- Where is a good place to get them?
- Are petri dishes better than test tubes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Screw ons are important for maintaining the moisture content.  Stoppers can pop off accidentally and ruin the culture.
2. Regarding sanitation, its easiest to just purchase individually packaged sterile tubes.
3. I'd suggest looking at VWR scientific or Fisher Scientific.
4. Petri dishes are for a different part of the process over slants.  So, no IMO.